# transform character varying [] to character varying postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have multiple input files that I want to run through the same SQL file. Sometimes a column that I run a regular expression on is an character varying[] and sometimes that same column in a different file is a character varying without the []. I want to make sure that it does not matter whether the input file is a character varying with or without the [].

The following works for an individual file:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE character varying;
UPDATE table SET column = left(column , length(column )-1);
UPDATE table SET column = right(column , length(column )-1);
```

When changing the type from character varying[] to character varying it keeps the brackets that I have to remove with an update statement. I am not managing to create a solution that works for both input files.

I think this direction of thought might be the answer but PL SQL is difficult for me: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-if-else-statements/ . Working on this at the moment but not sure if I am heading in the right direction:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
   ??? a integer := 10;
   ??? b integer := 10;
BEGIN 
  IF column === character varying[] THEN 
     ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE character varying;
     UPDATE table SET column = left(column , length(column )-1);
     UPDATE table SET column = right(column , length(column )-1);
  ELSE
     RAISE NOTICE 'column is a character varying';
  END IF;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing the following:

```
ALTER TABLE elektriciteitskabel ALTER COLUMN link_href TYPE character varying;
UPDATE elektriciteitskabel SET link_href = replace(link_href, '{', '');
UPDATE elektriciteitskabel SET link_href = replace(link_href, '}', '');
```